# Python - add a list of dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a `dictionary` called component and a `list` of `dictionaries` called allocations.
I want to be able to put the allocations under a component as a nested `dictionary`. kind of like so:

```
Allocations[
    allocation1 : {
        key : value
    },
    allocation2  {
        key : value
    }
]
```

My desired output:

```
Component1 : {
   key:value
   allocations : [allocation1 : {
                            key : value
                         }
                 ,allocation2 : {
                            key : value
                         }
               ]
}
```

I came from Java, and i realize there is no `append` that I can use.
I tried this and obviously didnt work:

```
            #allocate this under the selected component - DIDNT WORK
            component["allocations"][] = allocation
```

How can I create a list of dictionaries in a dictionary?

Comment: what is `allocation`?

Comment: @PaulRooney thought about that, but how should i add another allocation to the list? would it overwrite the previous one? You might have guessed this piece of code is inside the loop for allocations

Comment: @eyllanesc it's a dictionary, as stated in the question

Comment: what is `component`?

Comment: @eyllanesc wow, you should start reading more attentively

Comment: the first code that samples is not valid in python, improve your examples.

Comment: I have read your question clearly but your example is not the best, the codes are not adequate regarding the syntax.

Comment: your questions are clearly stated on the very first sentence. cleary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply assign it:

```
component["allocations"] = some_list
```

For instance, if you want a new, empty one:

```
component["allocations"] = []
```

or:

```
component["allocations"] = list()
```

Then, manipulate the list as usual:

```
component["allocations"].append(some_object)
```

Comment: awesome. that was simple. silly me. thanks! needed to wait to accept this.